# Ternary operator with SamplerStates

Tags: directx, hlsl, direct3d, directx-12, direct3d12

Is it possible to do something like this in HLSL:

```
SamplerState Sampler0 : register(s0, space1);
SamplerState Sampler1 : register(s1, space1);

int samplerIndex;
// ...

float4 color = texture.Sample(samplerIndex == 1 ? Sampler0 : Sampler1, uv);
```

I got an error that: `local resource not guaranteed to map to unique global resource`

Comment: Which compiler are you using? FXC? DXC?  Are you using the HLSL 2021 syntax with DXC?

Comment: DXC, I guess it's just impossible to copy static samplers

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, you are better off either:

(a) Building the same shader twice with two different static samplers.

-or-

(b) Use heap-based samplers so you can switch it out.

> For examples of various 'combinations' handling, see [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/tree/main/Src/Shaders)